# Solving for x using arctan.

Tags: trigonometry

I am having the hardest time solving the following trigonometric equation.  Can anyone help please?  Thank you.

Solve for x. [Hint: Let $\\u = \tan^{-1}(x)$ and $\\v = tan^{-1}(2x)$.  Solve the equation $\\u+v = \frac{π}{4}$ by taking the tangent of each side.]

$\tan^{-1}(x) +\tan^{-1}(2x)= \frac{π}{4}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have that $$\tan(a+b)=\dfrac{\tan a+\tan b}{1-\tan a\tan b}.$$ Applying this we get

$$\tan(\tan^{-1}x+\tan^{-1}(2x))=\dfrac{\tan (\tan^{-1}x)+\tan (\tan^{-1}(2x))}{1-\tan (\tan^{-1}x)\tan (\tan^{-1}(2x))}=\dfrac{x+2x}{1-2x^2}=\tan\frac{\pi}{4}=1.$$

That is, we have the equation $$3x=1-2x^2$$ or equivalently $$2x^2+3x-1=0.$$ Its solutions are $$\dfrac{-3\pm \sqrt{17}}{4}.$$

Comment: Thanks for your help.  The answer is the positive version of this right?  I am thinking that because tan(π/4)  is positive 1.

(−3+√(17))/4

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Use their hint and take the tangent of each side - you get $\tan(u+v)=\tan(\frac{\pi}{4})$. The following identity may be useful: $$\tan(a+b)=\frac{\tan(a)+\tan(b)}{1-\tan(a)\tan(b)}$$

Answer (score 0):

Among the useful trigonometric identities, try to memorize $$\tan^{-1}(a)\pm\tan^{-1}(b)=\tan^{-1}\frac{a\pm b}{1\mp ab}$$ So, using $a=x$ and $b=2x$ $$\tan^{-1}(x)+\tan^{-1}(2x)=\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{3x}{1-x^2}\right)$$ Then, the equation reduces to $$\frac{3x}{1-x^2}=1$$